# Can a Windows Jenkins Master have a Linux Jenkins Slave?

Tags: jenkins

I have setup lots of Windows Masters with Windows Slaves.

I have instructions for setting up a Linux Master.

However, what I would really like to do is to setup a Linux (ubuntu) Slave on a Windows master.

The issue is that my Windows master doesn't have a SSH option for slaves, so none of the Linux Slave instructions seem to apply.

Any ideas if this is possible and if so, how to go about it?

Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any major differences between running a master on different operating systems.

I thought the [SSH Slaves plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin) came installed by default, but if not, you can try installing it from the plugin centre.

Comment: Ah . . . enlightenment . . . somebody disabled that plugin - THANK YOU!